# How can I concatenate several vectors of unique pointers

Tags: c++, functional-programming, unique-ptr, range-v3, value-categories

### The original use-case

The usecase is that I have a function to retrieve some factories derived from `FooFactory`,

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FooFactory>> facts = getFactories();
```

and each factory can create some derived objects of base class `Foo`,

```cpp
struct FooFactory {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> getFoos();
};
```

and I want to call `getFoos` for all the factories `facts` and collect all the `Foo`s in a single `std::vector`.

### A naive solution

A naive solution is the following, where the `Foo`s are `push_back`ed on the `foos` vector one by one in a nested `for` loop.

```cpp
constexpr auto getFoos = [](auto const& fooFactories) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
    for (auto const& factory : fooFactories) {
        for (auto&& foo : factory->getFoos()) {
            foos.push_back(std::move(foo));
        }
    }
    return foos;
};

auto foos = getFoos(facts);
```

However this requires frequent reallocation of `foos`. A small improvement consists in doing `foos.reserve(foos.size() + factory->getFoos().size())` right before the inner `for` loop, which means that `foos` is reallocated "only" `fooFactories.size()` times. Another improvement would consist in accumulating the sizes of the `fooFactories` first, `reserve` that much space in `foos`, and then go for the nested for loop above.

However, any such solution seems overly verbose and low lever, where all I really want to do is to `getFoos()` from each element of `fooFactories` and join them together in a single vector.

### The functional programming way

#### Ideal - not compiling

In the spirit of [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) this would amount to the following (I've generically commented `range` to avoid writing the actual, long-to-write, types):

```cpp
auto foos = facts                           // vector<unique_ptr<FooFactory>>
          | transform(&FooFactory::getFoos) // range<vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>>
          | join                            // range<unique_ptr<Foo>>
          | to_vector;                      // vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>, COMPILE-TIME ERROR
```

However, this seems far from working, as implied by the comment, for the reason that `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

#### Sub-optimal solution - but is it legal?

Playing around with the above snippet, I eventually found a solution in releasing the pointers and reconstructing them right after `join`:

```cpp
auto foos = facts                                         // vector<unique_ptr<FooFactory>>
          | transform(&FooFactory::getFoos)               // range<vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>>
          | join                                          // range<unique_ptr<Foo>>
          | transform(&std::unique_ptr<Foo>::release)     // range<Foo*>
          | transform(construct¹<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>()) // range<unique_ptr<Foo>>
          | to_vector;                                    // vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

### My question(s)

1. Is the last snippet above legal? Or does it invoke UB?
2. If it is UB (or invalid in any other way), why is that?
3. If it is legal, can you explain why the trick of `release`+re`construct` work?

The complete working code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MnTcav9P8).

---

(¹) That `construct` is [`boost::hof::construct`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/construct.html) from the [Boost.HOF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/index.html#) library. In short, `construct<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>()` is a wrapper around the constructor of `std::unique_ptr`, i.e. it behaves more or less like this lambda: `[](auto* p){ return std::unique_ptr<Foo>{p}; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've noted the issue is that `views::join` is a view over lvalues. Just move from them:

```cpp
auto foos = facts                    // vector<unique_ptr<FooFactory>>&
  | transform(&FooFactory::getFoos)  // range<vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>>
  | join                             // range<unique_ptr<Foo>&>
  | ranges::move                     // range<unique_ptr<Foo>&&>
  | to_vector;                       // vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

Note that the composition of `&std::unique_ptr<Foo>::release` followed by `construct<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>()` is equivalent to `[](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& x) -> std::unique_ptr<Foo> { return std::move(x); }`, which is very similar to what `ranges::move` is doing (lvalue -> xvalue instead of lvalue -> prvalue):

```cpp
auto foos = facts
          | transform(&FooFactory::getFoos)
          | join
          // | transform(&std::unique_ptr<Foo>::release)
          // | transform(hof::construct<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>())
          | transform([](std::unique_ptr<Foo>& x) { return std::move(x); })

          | to_vector;
```

Comment: About the exception un-safeness, you refer to the fact that an exception can be throw between the release and the creation, thus causing a leak?

Comment: @Enlico Exactly. Though on second advancing the iterators of `transform(construct<unique_ptr>())` releases then constructs a new unique_ptr immediately, so it might be safe anyways

Answer (score 0):

In crafting the question, I think I ended up understanding why the code compiles, i.e. I think I answered the question 3 above:

- `join` being a view, when dereferenced (well, the iterator on it), returns an lvalue reference to the range element, i.e. `std::unique_ptr<Foo>&`,
- so `to_vector` tries to copy them, failing because `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` is not copyable;
- `transform(&std::unique_ptr<Foo>::release)` returns a range of bare `Foo*`s rvalues,
- and `transform(construct<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>())` takes each `Foo*` and generates an rvalue of type `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` out of it,
- so that `to_vector` can `std::move` those rvalues into the final `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`.

So the comments in the code above were not quite accurate. Here they are corrected:

```
auto foos = facts                                         // vector<unique_ptr<FooFactory>>
          | transform(&FooFactory::getFoos)               // range<vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>>
          | join  /* comment change on this line ---> */  // range<unique_ptr<Foo>&>
          | transform(&std::unique_ptr<Foo>::release)     // range<Foo*>
          | transform(construct¹<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>()) // range<unique_ptr<Foo>>
          | to_vector;                                    // vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

The other two questions, though, remain, even if I'm inclined to think that the code is indeed legal.